# What is the equivalent of Matlab 'fscanf' in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, scanf

The Matlab function `fscanf()` seems to be very powerful. Is there any equivalent of the same in python (or numpy)?

Specifically I want to read a matrix from file but I don't want to iterate through each line to read the matrix.
Something of this sort (from matlab for reading a 2D 1000x1000 matrix):

```
matrix = fscanf(fopen('input.txt'),'%d',[1000,1000]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has no built-in `fscanf` function. The closest way to do it is to read the file line by line and use regular expressions.

[Numpy](https://numpy.org/) (the Matlab-like Python library), however, has a function that allows to read a file and construct an array from is content : [`numpy.fromfile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) (or, as suggested in the other answers, [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) may be more suitable in this case).

Comment: `numpy.fromfile` is very low-level. If you want to read in binary data or a very simply formatted text file very, very quickly, then it's a good option.  Generally speaking, though, the OP would probably be better off with `numpy.loadtxt` or `numpy.genfromtxt` for this purpose. `fromfile` is better suited binary data, though it can handle simple text formats as well.  `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` are much, much more flexible, but slightly slower. (The difference between the two is that `genfromtxt` handles missing values while `loadtxt` can't)

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer in case the OP did not read your insightful comment.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure there is not, but iterating isn't too hard.  This would do it:

```
matrix = []
for i in open('input.txt'):
    matrix.append( map(int, i.split()) )
```

If you need something more complex (i.e. not just ints separated by single characters), regular expressions may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think Wookai answer is incorrect. I think [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) is what you look for.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at numpy? - http://www.scipy.org/Download

By the way, fscanf internally stores the data in column order - So I don't think there will be any efficiency gain.
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fscanf.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the pythonic way to do it would be to open the file and read in the data into a `list` of `list`s using list comprehensions.

(I'm using data from a string for clarity, and reading it in as if from a file using `StringIO`.)

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> data_file="1 2 3 4 5 6\n7 8 9 10 11 12\n13 14 15 16 17 18\n19 20 21 22 23 24\n"
>>> reader=StringIO(data_file)
>>> array=[map(int, reader.readline().split()) for i in xrange(4)]
>>> array
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]
```

As an earlier answer mentions, numpy has a more direct method.