# Python: read various data-type from file

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm switching from `matlab` to `python`.
The data I want to import is like this

```
4
6
2
1
2.0E8
0.2
0.002

1 2 6
2 3 4
2 4 5
2 5 6

0 0
1 0
2 0
2 1
1 1
0 1

4 0 -150

1 1 1
6 1 1
```

And this is how I read it in `matlab`

```
FP1=fopen('471220580.txt','rt');
NELEM=fscanf(FP1,'%d',1);
NPION=fscanf(FP1,'%d',1);
NVFIX=fscanf(FP1,'%d',1);
NFORCE=fscanf(FP1,'%d',1);
YOUNG=fscanf(FP1,'%e',1);
POISS=fscanf(FP1,'%f',1);
THICK =fscanf(FP1,'%f',1);
LNODS=fscanf(FP1,'%d',[3, NELEM])';  
COORD=fscanf(FP1,'%f',[2,NPION])';  
FORCE=fscanf(FP1,'%f',[3,NFORCE])';  
FIXED=fscanf(FP1,'%d',[3,NVFIX])';
```

How can I import these data in `python`? I didn't find an equivalent for `fscanf` in `python`.

For [What is the equivalent of Matlab 'fscanf' in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402468/what-is-the-equivalent-of-matlab-fscanf-in-python)
`numpy.loadtxt` requires `Each row in the text file must have the same number of values`. This is not a good fit in my case.

Comment: You haven't responded on your last question still... might want to slow down with the questions a bit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the equivalent of Matlab 'fscanf' in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402468/what-is-the-equivalent-of-matlab-fscanf-in-python)

Comment: @DonkeyKong, I've checked that answer, `numpy.loadtxt` requires `Each row in the text file must have the same number of values.`.

Comment: @DonkeyKong, as for my previous question, it seems that people think is not good to create matrix directly in script, so I create this post instead. The previous one is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Loop across the lines in the file like

```
for line in open("file.txt"):
     parse(line)
```

The `parse` method is a method which takes the line as input and output an integer, float or a list of ints.

For integer -> `var = int(line)`

For float -> `var = float(line)`

For list of ints -> `var = map(int, line.split())`

For a matrix -> consider that you read want a `m X n` matrix.
So read in `m` lines, from above loop like -

```
matrix = []

count = m
for line in open():
    if count > 0:
        matrix.append(map(int, line.split()))
```

Comment: But how can I read it as a matrix? `LNODS=fscanf(FP1,'%d',[3, NELEM]);` This would generate a matrix.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('471220580.txt') as text_file:
    all_numbers = text_file.read().split("\n")
    all_numbers = filter(None, all_numbers)
    #the all_numbers list contains all the distinct values from the file
    #Now to initialize various variables you can use following methods:

    #Method1:
    NELEM = all_numbers[0]
    NPION = all_numbers[1]
    #and so on ... 

    #Note: Keep in mind that the values stored in these variables is of type str


   #Method2:
   NELEM, NIPON ,... = all_numbers
```

The advantage of using `Method1` over `Method2` is that you can use type casting in method1 , and you can achieve this is by using `var1 = type(var)`

```
NELEM = int(all_numbers[0])
NPION = int(all_numbers[1])
POISS = float(all_numbers[5])
```

For the lines 9-12 which constitute a matrix we can represent matrix as list of lists.

```
matrix_row1 = map(int, all_numbers[9])    #[1, 2, 3]
matrix_row2 = map(int, all_numbers[10])   #[4, 5, 6]
matrix_row3 = map(int, all_numbers[11])   #[7, 8, 9]

matrix = [matrix_row1, matrix_row2, matrix_row3]
#[[1, 2, 3],
# [4, 5, 6],
# [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: But How can I locate the `matrix`? I need to manually count the numbers?

Comment: which `matrix` are you talking about ?

Comment: For example, from `line 9-12` is a matrix. But it seems like we turned all numbers into an array? How can I import that into a `matrix` conviniently?